# What is a public interface in C++

Tags: c++, reference, terminology

On [isocpp - faq for references](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references) it states:

> References are usually preferred over pointers whenever you don’t need “reseating”. This usually means that references are most useful in a class’s **public** interface. References typically appear on the skin of an object, and pointers on the inside.

So, what is a public interface in c++ ? If possible provide an example.

Comment: Just any class members which are visible in `public` scope?

Comment: The public interface of a class is the set of public methods and member variables that a user of the class has access to.

Comment: @rsjaffe yes, I was thrown off by the "interface" word I thought it was a design pattern. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_interface